# Render only Items with a specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I render my Item's via `<%= render @items%>`

I added a migration `AddCatIdToItems cat_id:string`

**Cat_id's:** testA, testB, testC.

how can I render only items with the specific id `testA`?

e.g.: `<&= @items.where(:cat_id => '1')&>`

I use a seed file to populate the Item's. e.g.:

```
Tag.create([
            { name: 'example' },
            { name: 'example2' },
            { name: 'example3' }
           ])
```

How can i pass the cat_id into that?

is `{ name: 'example', cat_id:1 }` working?

Comment: Why don't you filter your records when you fetch them from DB?

Comment: please show how you set `@items` variable in your controller.

Comment: Could you join me in Chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38896/minijohn

Comment: The code is crappy. 1. Query in view is ugly; 2. View thinks too much on deciding which object to show; 3. There is no guarantee such id is in `@items`; Better to provide use case, there is better solution than fixing current code directly.

Comment: Could you answer that solution please?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, it's hard to know your real purpose from the view code only. Could you describe the real problem you want to solve and mention some controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking for. But I guess this is what you want

```
@items = Item.where("cat_id LIKE '%testA%'")
```

If you want to select all the items that have a specific cat_id, then

```
 @items = Item.where(:cat_id => 'testA')
```

Comment: I'm searching for a method to render items ONLY with a specific cat_id.

Comment: I still need the render @items to work normally. I have 4 tabs, in which i need to render 4 specific cat_id's. That code goes into my controller right?